# CSSlint 'overqualified' error with unknown tokens '∩╗┐'

Tags: rhino, csslint

For some reason when I run Css lint with Rhino I get the following errors:

[image: Csslint error]

I'm working with:

- Windows server Server 2008
- Visual Studio 2012 (MVC 4)
- Java version "1.7.0_21"
- rhino version 1_6R7
- csslint-rhino.js from this url: "https://raw.github.com/stubbornella/csslint/master/release/csslint-rhino.js

My elements look like this:

```
.body {
}

.testelement {

}

.loadingIndicator {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-image: url('/images/loadingIndicator.gif');
}
```

It seems some kind of encoding issue, but I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have found the problem myself.

In Visual Studio 2012 the files are saved as UTF-8. Apparently CSS lint can't handle this encoding. UTF-8 without BOM seems to work without problems though.